# How to show No Results screen on UISearchDisplayController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

How can I manually show No Results on a UISearchDisplayController?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, it would be enough to set sections number to 0 during search.